# If JSP page object is a reference to the servlet object and has attributes, how come the servlet class does not have attributes?

Tags: jsp, object, servlets, implicit

Non of the servlet APIs(Servlet, GenericServlet and HttpServlet) have methods to set and get attributes at class scope. However, The implicit Page object, which is a reference to the servlet object, from JSP can define attributes at class scope. 
how is this possible?

Comment: Are you asking why a Servlet is not a JSP page? How does that make sense?

Comment: No that not what am asking. In servlets, we can specify attributes at three scopes: request, application and session. In jsp, however, we can specify at four scopes: request, application, session and page. JSP gets converted to Servlets. My question is since servlets don't have page scope, what happens to JSP attributes defined at page scope when it gets translated to a servlet?

Comment: They just stay in page scope.